# how to get previous month or last two month data in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

how to get previous month or last two month data in oracle.
My date format is YYYY,MM,DD.

from google search i got those solution,

```
select * from IM_LAPTOP
where ADD_DATE >= add_months(sysdate, -12);

select *   
  from IM_LAPTOP
 where ADD_DATE between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1));
```

But its showing not a valid month

Comment: Is `add_date` actually defined as a `date`?  Or as a `varchar2`?  Or as a `number`?  If you're storing dates, you really ought to use the proper data type (`date`).  But the error seems to imply that you're using the wrong data type.

Answer (score 1):

> My date format is YYYY,MM,DD

Unless you are using a string to store dates then, no, it is not; a `DATE` is a binary data type (consisting of 1-byte for each of: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and it always has those components) and it has no format.

> how to get previous month or last two month data in oracle

To get the data from 2 months before this instant in time (i.e. if it is now `2021-04-05 16:39:24` and you want it from `2021-02-05 16:39:24`, two months prior) then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_column >= ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -2 )
```

To get the data starting from midnight on the 1st day of last month:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_column >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
```

If you only want the data from the preceding month then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_column >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
AND    date_column <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
```

If your "date" is actually a `VARCHAR2` column with the format `YYYY,MM,DD` then you should change it to a `DATE` column but if for some reason you cannot then at least the characters are in order of highest-to-least significance and you can perform an alphanumeric comparison and just wrap the right-hand side of the filters in `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_column >= TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -2 ), 'YYYY,MM,DD' )
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_column >= TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -2 ), 'YYYY,MM,DD' )

this query showing all of data, not showing last month or last two month data. please help

Comment: This query work for me.. Thank you



select *   
  from IM_LAPTOP
 where to_date(add_date,'yyyy/mm/dd') between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-2) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-2))